# What is the type of the variable in do-notation here in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, do-notation

The codes below looks quite clear:

```
do 
  x <- Just 3
  y <- Just "!"
  Just (show x ++ y)
```

Here the type of `x` is `Num` and `y` is `String`. (`<-` here is used to take actual value out of the Monad)

However, this snippet looks not so clear to me:

```
import Control.Monad.Instances
addStuff :: Int -> Int
addStuff = do
  a <- (* 2)
  b <- (+ 10)
  return (a + b)
```

What is the type of `a` and type of `b` here? It seems they act like a `Num`, but `a <- (* 2)` and `b <- (+ 10)` looks cryptic here...

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: `<-` *Does not* 'remove' the value from a monad. It is syntactic sugar that *represents* pulling out a value, but is actually just manipulating it in a specific manner. For this reason, you can treat functions as monads, because, while you can't literally 'pull out' the result of a function, you can pipe functions together to make another.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you've stumbled upon a kind of weird monad.

The monad in question is the `Monad ((->) r)`. Now, what does that mean? Well, it's the monad of functions of the form `r -> *`. I.e., of functions that take the same type of input.

You asked what the type of `a` and `b` are in this instance. Well, they are both `Num a => a`, but that doesn't really explain much.

Intuitively, we can understand the monad like this: A monadic value is a function that takes a value of type `r` as input. Whenever we bind in the monad, we take that value and pass it to the bound function.

I.e., in our `addStuff` example, if we call `addStuff 5`, then `a` is bound to `(*2) 5` (which is `10`), and `b` is bound to `(+10) 5` (which is `15`).

Let's see a simpler example from this monad to try to understand how it works precisely:

```
mutate = do a <- (*2)
            return (a + 5)
```

If we desugar this to a bind, we get:

```
mutate = (*2) >>= (\a -> return (a + 5))
```

Now, this doesn't help much, so let's use [the definition of bind](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-621) for this monad:

```
mutate = \ r -> (\a -> return (a + 5)) ((*2) r) r
```

This reduces to

```
mutate = \ r -> return ((r*2) + 5) r
```

Which we using the definition that `return` is `const`, can reduce to

```
mutate = \ r -> (r*2) + 5
```

Which is a function, that multiplies a number by 2, and then adds 5.

That's one weird monad.

Comment: You might want to name the monad (Reader) so that the asker can search for resources about it. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 'wierd' monad; it's certainly difficult to get your head around at first, but it, to my mind, is the perfect example of a Monad as an unreachable computation, or computational context.

Answer (score 9):

Given `addStuff`

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int
addStuff = do
  a<-(*2)
  b<-(+10)
  return (a+b)
```

the definition desugars into

```
addStuff = 
    (* 2) >>= \a -> 
        (+ 10) >>= \b -> 
            return (a + b)
```

Hovering over the `>>=` in [fpcomplete online editor](https://www.fpcomplete.com/page/project-build) shows

```
:: Monad m => forall a b. 
              (m a       ) -> (a   -> m b       ) -> (m b       )
::            (Int -> a  ) -> (a   -> Int -> b  ) -> (Int -> b  )
::            (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
```

That leads us to believe we use a Monad instance for functions. Indeed if we look at the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-621), we see

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

---

Using this newly obtained information we can evaluate the `addStuff` function ourselves.

Given the initial expression

```
(* 2) >>= ( \a -> (+10) >>= \b -> return (a + b) )
```

we substitute using the `>>=` definition, giving us (in the following `{}`, `[]`, `()` just illustrate different depth of `()`)

```
\r1 -> {\a -> (+10) >>= \b -> return (a + b)} {(* 2) r1} r1
```

simplify the second-to-last term inside the outermost lambda

```
\r1 -> {\a -> (+10) >>= \b -> return (a + b)} {r1 * 2} r1
```

apply `{r1 * 2}` to `{\a -> ...}`

```
\r1 -> {(+10) >>= \b -> return ((r1 * 2) + b)} r1
```

substitute remaining `>>=` with its definition again

```
\r1 -> {\r2 -> [\b -> return (r1 * 2 + b)] [(+10) r2] r2} r1
```

simplify second-to-last term inside inner lambda

```
\r1 -> {\r2 -> [\b -> return (r1 * 2 + b)] [r2 + 10] r2} r1
```

apply `[r2 + 10]` to `{\b -> ...}`

```
\r1 -> {\r2 -> [return (r1 * 2 + (r2 + 10))] r2} r1
```

apply `r1` to `{\r2 -> ...}`

```
\r1 -> {return (r1 * 2 + r1 + 10) r1}
```

substitute `return` with its definition

```
\r1 -> {const (r1 * 2 + r1 + 10) r1}
```

evaluate `const x _ = x`

```
\r1 -> {r1 * 2 + r1 + 10}
```

prettify

```
\x -> 3 * x + 10
```

finally we get

```
addStuff :: Int -> Int
addStuff = (+ 10) . (* 3)
```